# Could not find specified column in results

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net, asp

Tenho um código para fazer busca em duas tabelas, uma busca o logotipo e a outra as imagens, a primeira ele faz normalmente, faz a leitura e tudo mais, no segundo ele já da erro, o código é o seguinte:

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = GetConnection())
        {
            using (MySqlCommand command = GetCommand(conn))
            {
                command.CommandText = @"

                        SELECT
                            tb_logos.*
                        FROM tb_logos
                        WHERE tb_logos.id_logo = @id_logo

                    ;";

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_logo", id);

                using (IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        post = Preencher(reader);
                    }
                }
                command.CommandText = @"

                        SELECT tb_logo_imagem.ds_imagem FROM tb_logo_imagem WHERE id_logo = @img_id_logo;";

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img_id_logo", id);

                using (IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            post.Imagens.Add(reader["tb_logo_imagem.ds_imagem"].ToString());
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            post.Imagens = null;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Ele informa o seguinte erro:

> Could not find specified column in results

E quando mudo o `reader` para `reader["ds_imagem"]` ele informa esse outro erro:

> Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.

Eu executei a query diretamente no mysql e retornou o resultado normalmente.

Comment: Em que linha dá erro? O que faz o método `Preendher(reader);`? Qual a estrutura da tabela?

Comment: @RonaldoAraújoAlves o método insere as informações do banco na classe, o erro ocorre no comando: `post.Imagens.Add(reader["tb_logo_imagem.ds_imagem"].ToString());`